# Using a regression tree to split a population into groups with similar characteristics

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am trying to find a smart way to split and group 30.0000+ households into bins of minimum 100 households each based on different characteristics such as primary heating type, square meters, housetype, inhabitants and somewhat similar electricty consumption.

Therefore I am experimenting with a regression tree and have so far written the following R code:

```
xplr=ctree_control(mincriterion = 0.999, minsplit=150, minbucket=100
fit <- ctree(LatestAvgDailykWh ~ HouseType + PrimaryHeatingType + SquareMeters, data=na.omit(dataset), control = xplr)
```

That results in a decision tree, which is fine. What I eventually want to arrive at is actually:

1. A definition of each group (the rules and values of the regressors that characterizes the groups) so that a group can be defined by for example Housetype = Apartment, PrimaryHeatingType = DistrictHeating, SquareMeters > 60 etc.
2. What group (bin) each specific household is placed into to see if that household spends more or less electricity than its peer group.

In order to see how the tree has been build I have experimented with:

```
partykit:::.list.rules.party
```

following this blogpost:https://rmanic.wordpress.com/2016/05/19/creating-a-well-formatted-decision-tree-with-partykit-and-listing-the-rules-of-the-nodes/

but I run into different kinds of data manipulation issues when trying to reproduce the script and I am not sure it will bring me al the way. So if anyone has input on how to nicely format and output the rules that would be great.

Comment: You could try `kmeans`.

Comment: To expand on the comment of @G.Grothendieck,  regression trees are used for regression. Your problem sounds more like you need cluster analysis. kmeans would be a reasonable place to start.

Comment: The thing is that I do not know up front how many clusters I want. All I know is that I do not want a leaf node with fewer than around 100 households. My initial approach was to hard code the groups making a group for every combination of housetype, primay heating type, inhabitants and so on resulting in some combinations with only one household, which does not make sense when I want to compare evry household to a group that looks most like it. That's when I started looking into a regression tree, to let that do the splitting on the categories based on the underlying electricity consumption.